# Need to zip individual files of certain size & remove the original files in unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, zip

I want to zip individual files gotten from an output & delete the original files. The objective is to find files greater than 9MB and zip each file of that size individually & remove its original instance. Something like this..

```
find test* -type f - size +9M 
zip -m <filenames (from the above output)> <individual filename.zip>
```

expected output -

```
test_abc1.txt.1.zip
test_abc2.txt.2.zip
test_abc3.txt.zip
```

Comment: Using zip on a single file is unusual, especially on a unixy platform where you'd normally just use a file compressor like gzip, zstd, bzip2, etc.

Comment: I need to send those zipped files via an email attachment to be opened on a system which can only extract zipped files. So zip is the best way I can think of doing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For zipping individual files with `find`, the main problem is how to generate the zip filenames automatically; for that you can use shell parameter expansions in a `find -exec` inline script:

```sh
find test* -type f -size +9M -exec sh -c '
    for f
    do
        z=${f##*/}.zip
        zip -j -m "$z" "$f"
    done
' _ {} +
```

###### notes:

- The `z=${f##*/}.zip` strips the directory path component of `$f` and append a `.zip` at the end; for example, if `$f` is `test1/file.txt`, then `$z` will be `file.txt.zip`.
  If you also want to replace the file extension by `.zip` then you can use `z=${f##*/} z=${z%.*}.zip` instead.
- The `-j` option of `zip` is for stripping the directory path inside the ZIP archive.
- The `-m` option of `zip` is for removing the input file(s) after successful generation of the ZIP archive.